# Spring Mongodb bi-directional dbref

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

Is it possible to have bi-directional dbref in mongodb (like what we can have in relational database, bi-directional one-to-many relationship). If possible how this can be represented in Mongodb and also using Spring-mongodb. The exact scenario I facing is as below

Let's say we would like to build a forum. Forum can have multiple forum topics. Each topic can posts but post should be tagged with one forum topic. There is a one-to-many relationship between forum --> topics and Topic --> posts, also there is relationship from posts --> forum topic. Given the situation how this can be handled using Spring-mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not support bidirectional dbref, First of all as you kow. its is a Document based data storage using key-value pairs to store each data. If you want to store the Forum Data inside mongodb, you have to follow this particular document Structure

```
public class Forum {

  @Id
  private String forunId;
  private String forumTitle;
  private String description;
  private Date createdDate;

  @DBRef
  private List<Topic> topics

}

public class Topic {

  @Id
  private String topicId;
  private String topicName;

  @DBRef
  private List<Post> posts

}

public class Post {

  @Id
  private String postId;
  private String comment;

}
```

Suggessions requested